# Why is root running java

Tags: 14.04, java, root

Just noticed that `root` is running a process named `java`.

Is there really an Ubuntu system level process that necessitates this, or is this a sign of some rouge software or incorrect installation of a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Ubuntu doesn't even have Java installed, so no system processes that use it too.

It's hard to tell what it is with the information you give. It could be part of a package you've installed, or it could be a rogue program.

Best thing to do is look at the path of the Java executable. Is there a package name you've installed in the path? Verify if the Java executable is legit by going to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com), searching for the package name and checking the file list for the Java executable.

If you really want to be sure if it's the original file of the package you can download the `tar.gz` and match the md5 sum.

Comment: Thanks! looking at the process properties, I found it was a "crashplan" background process.